# BackHandler Navigation in Drawer Navigator and Main Stack Navigator in React Navigation

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am not being able to get the backHandler (Hardware Back Button on Android) to work with my Drawer and Stack Navigation on React-Navigation
The back button works perfectly on the homepage screen and but it stops working once i navigate to next screen wether the screen is in the drawer screen or in the stack. 
Here is my both Drawer and MainStackNavigator.

Note: Combining the two didn't work for me as both of them are not part of a component and I am using redux in my app

Anyone has any idea how this could be resolved?

DrawerNavigatior

```
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Homep: Homepage,
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Shop: ShopScreen,
    Order: OrdersScreen,
    Wishlist: WishlistScreen,
    Search: SearchScreen,
    Profile: ProfileScreen,
    ShoppingBag: ShoppingBagScreen,


  },
```

MainStackNavigator

```
const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Drawer: { screen: DrawerStackNavigator },
    CategoryProductGrid: { screen: CategoryProductGridScreen },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
    Contact: { screen: ContactUsScreen },
    EditProfile: { screen: EditProfileScreen },
    ShippingAddress: { screen: ShippingAddressScreen },
    LocList: { screen: LocationList },
    ShippingMethod: { screen: ShippingMethodScreen },
    PaymentMethod: { screen: PaymentMethodScreen },
    AddACard: { screen: AddACardScreen },
    Checkout: { screen: CheckoutScreen },
    Bag: { screen: ShoppingBagScreen },


  },
```

I am using BackHander event listener as follows

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backHandler.remove()
  }

  handleBackPress = () => {

    Alert.alert(
      'Exit App',
      'Exiting the application?',
      [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'OK',
          onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()
        }
      ],
      {
        cancelable: false
      }
    );
    return true;

  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wohoo, after a week of searching and trying different ways
The solution was really simple, I had to move the drawer navigation and put it all under the MainstackNavigator so the Return back hardware button will work properly

Comment: I have the same problem but I dont understand your answer , would please share your solution code

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer at first place, there is note "Why not use component lifecycle methods#
At first, you may be inclined to use componentDidMount to subscribe for the back press event and componentWillUnmount to unsubscribe, or use useEffect to add the listener. This approach will not work - learn more about this in navigation lifecycle. " https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling/#why-not-use-component-lifecycle-methods that you should not use in lifecycle methods, what is case showed above